# Know which URL is being loaded Blackberry

Tags: browser, blackberry, java-me

So I am using a blackberry `BrowserSession` to load a url, I loaded the url. This url has buttons when you click on them the url changes, I want to know when is the url changing and when it changes to a certain url I want to add a pop up window. Does anyone know how to do that?

If you program in Android, we use

```
    shouldOverrideUrlLoading(String url){}
```

I am not sure if there is one like that in BlackBerry. If you can check which url is being loaded without using `BrowserSession`, then that would work too.

Comment: Which minimum OS do you need to support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use BrowerSession to launch a URL, the page is rendered in the BlackBerry Browser process and your app can't access events in it. What you need to to is load your URL within a `BrowserField` - the BlackBerry equivalent of WebView.

If you want to show the popup after the page has loaded, implement the `BrowserFieldListener` interface to know when the page has loaded.

If you want to show the popup when the user clicks on link you will have to implement your own `BrowserFieldNavigationRequestHandler`.

Here is the full code.

```
static void showScreen() {
    MainScreen screen = new MainScreen();
    final BrowserField bf = new BrowserField();
    final ProtocolController pc = (ProtocolController) bf.getController();

    pc.setNavigationRequestHandler("http", new BrowserFieldNavigationRequestHandler() {
        public void handleNavigation(BrowserFieldRequest request) throws Exception {
            intercept();  //Intercept the request and my handler
            InputConnection ic = pc.handleResourceRequest(request);
            bf.displayContent(ic, request.getURL());
        }
    });

    screen.add(bf);
    bf.requestContent("http://www.google.com");
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(screen);
}
```

Comment: how do I implement my own BrowserFieldNavigationRequestHandler